# After when I made add-migration and update-database problem occur

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to add a new model to my project 
here is model

```
 public class Marking
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdMakring{get;set;}
        public int IdMema { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Author")]
        public string Authorr {get;set;}

    }
```

in model memyContext I added

```
public DbSet<Marking> Marking { get; set; }
```

I did add-migration and update-database

```
add-migration initialll -Context  MemeGenerator.Data.ApplicationDbContext
add-migration initialll -Context  memyContext
update-database -Context  MemeGenerator.Data.ApplicationDbContext
```

when I made this, error show:

[image]

I tried ones more update-database but it didn't help. Somebody see how can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you have two contexts but only ran update database on one of them. Error says to apply migrations to memyContext.

Answer (score 0):

**try to execute specifying migration name**

example :

```
dotnet ef database update 20190524150901_initialll
```

Comment: ```dotnet ef database update 20190524195648_initiale --context memyContext``` I done this and nothing change ,that same error ,in windows prompt I see a answer :There is already an object named 'Memy' in the database.-in red color-I don't know whether this mean that something go wrong?

Comment: dotnet ef database update <migration name> -p <Fullname project E.F> -s <Fullname project that contais connection string>